# Using Ruby to retrieve ids from JSON response

Tags: ruby, json

I am building an application using Ruby 2.0 where after parsing a string to JSON, I'm interested in retrieving all of the `game_id` fields listed below. After parsing has been completed, is there a trivial way in Ruby to map/collect through the parsed JSON response to do that? Here's an example of the JSON I'm working with.

```
{
    "season_type"=>"Regular",
    "sport"=>"NBA",
    "gamedate"=>"11/29/2013",
    "updated_at"=>"2013-11-29 23:35:17 UTC",
    "games"=>[
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Charlotte",
                "game_id"=>19089,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Milwaukee",
                "home_team_id"=>152,
                "gametime"=>"07:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>103
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Orlando",
                "game_id"=>19091,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"San Antonio",
                "home_team_id"=>117,
                "gametime"=>"07:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>110
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Toronto",
                "game_id"=>19092,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Miami",
                "home_team_id"=>118,
                "gametime"=>"07:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>115
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Atlanta",
                "game_id"=>19096,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Dallas",
                "home_team_id"=>91,
                "gametime"=>"07:30 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>95
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Boston",
                "game_id"=>19101,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Cleveland",
                "home_team_id"=>92,
                "gametime"=>"07:30 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>94
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Detroit",
                "game_id"=>19104,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"LA Lakers",
                "home_team_id"=>97,
                "gametime"=>"07:30 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>102
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Houston",
                "game_id"=>19106,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Brooklyn",
                "home_team_id"=>99,
                "gametime"=>"08:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>104
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Indiana",
                "game_id"=>19110,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Washington",
                "home_team_id"=>100,
                "gametime"=>"08:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>113
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Oklahoma City",
                "game_id"=>19108,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Golden State",
                "home_team_id"=>111,
                "gametime"=>"08:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>98
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Philadelphia",
                "game_id"=>19112,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"New Orleans",
                "home_team_id"=>106,
                "gametime"=>"08:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>114
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Denver",
                "game_id"=>19116,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"New York",
                "home_team_id"=>96,
                "gametime"=>"09:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>105
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Utah",
                "game_id"=>19119,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"Phoenix",
                "home_team_id"=>112,
                "gametime"=>"09:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>107
            }
        },
        {
            "game"=>{
                "home_team_name"=>"Sacramento",
                "game_id"=>19123,
                "visiting_team_name"=>"LA Clippers",
                "home_team_id"=>109,
                "gametime"=>"10:00 PM",
                "visiting_team_id"=>101
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
parsed_json['games'].map { |g| g['game']['game_id'] }
```